# What is the word/phrase that is used for 'that is all you get'?

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests, synonyms

For example,

"Guess vegetables are ____ for me since my mom banned any sort of meat in the house."

I was thinking of the phrase 'in stock' but I would like to know if there are any other phrases or synonyms for it.

Comment: Colloquially, you could use _it_: "Guess vegetables are it for me, since my mom banned any sort of meat in the house".

Comment: **Hobson's choice**  [[see PhraseFinder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/hobsons-choice.html)] (ie 'take it or leave it') is what you're presented with, but it doesn't fit your sample sentence.

Answer (score -1):

An appropriate expression for this is [**de rigueur**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/de%20rigueur):

> : prescribed or required by fashion, etiquette, or custom : PROPER
>   // … tattoos, of course, being *de rigueur* among the poetry set.

So, your example sentence would become:

> I guess vegetables are *de rigueur* for me since my mom banned any sort of meat in the house.

Although it's not wrong to have the *for me*, *de rigueur* is typically not followed by a preposition or prepositional phrase, so you could also remove those two words from the sentence.

Comment: "de rigueur" is perhaps weaker than what the OP seems to want. Just because something is "de rigueur", it's not absolutely required - it's merely usual or customary.

Comment: @StuartF The very definition that I quoted in my answer includes the wording *prescribed or required*. The words *usual or customary* are nowhere to be found …

Answer (score -1):

I would say the phrase you are looking for is ["my lot in life"](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/someone-s-lot-in-life).   MacMillian defines it as

> someone’s general situation in life, especially when this is not very good
>
> *Miss Wilkinson was never satisfied with her lot in life.*

It would work quite nicely if you strike for me, which becomes redundant. Other phrases that are similar my fate, my comeuppance, my destiny, etc., but these seem a little melodramatic for usage here.

Note that the usage of lot in this way has some Biblical connotations.  See

> Psalm 16:5-6
>
> “The LORD is the portion of mine inheritance and of my cup: thou maintainest my lot. The lines are fallen unto me in pleasant places; yea, I have a goodly heritage.”